# Excel restart numbering after blank cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns of data. Column B holds some data about tasks, column C holds data about who's doing it.  In column B there will be a heading of the main task and underneath will be subtasks.

What i want to do in column A is look at C1 which is blank and in A1 0.  When i copy down, it A2 will look at C2, sees something is in there, looks at A1 and sees that 0 is in there and puts 1 in A2.

A3 will look at C3, see data there, look at A2 and see that it is greater than 0 and add 1 to whatever is in A2 and so on.

I've tried for ages using different combinations of formula but i can't get it right.

Anyone did this before and how?!

[image: Screenshot and data layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to start the formula at `A2` rather than `A1`.  In `A1`, enter `0`. In `A2`, enter the following formula and fill down.

```
=IF(C2="",0,A1+1)
```

EDIT:

Based on your screen capture, this will give you exactly what you have there.
Leave `A1` blank.  Then in `A2` enter the following and fill down.

```
=IF(C2="","",IF(A1="",1,A1+1))
```

Comment: Many thanks.  So simple and I thought it was harder than that

Answer (score -1):

`=IF(C2=" ",0,C1+1)` in `A2` and drag down for your table. After that, copy and past values and in the and find and replace zero with blank.